# Is it possible to federate a customer's active directory to my SaaS app with SSO?

Tags: single-sign-on, saas, federation

I am working on setting up SSO for for our SaaS application.  As part of our SSO options, we are wanting to offer Active Directory.  Is it possible to do this like you would for google or github etc.?  It seems to me that each organization would have a different user pool meaning that their specific instance of AD would have to be registered as a SAML provider.  Am I understanding this right?  I know it is common to set up your own AD as a provider to your own apps, just not for external organizations.

Comment: Q: Is it possible for users of your SaaS app to use SSO against your customers' Active Directories?  A: Yes .. but it's not necessarily trivial.  SUGGESTIONS: 1) Read up on [Oauth2](https://oauth.net/2/).  2) Consider [MSAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-overview).  3) Consider 3rd party solutions like [Auth0](https://auth0.com/), Okta, Firebase, etc.  EXAMPLE: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/microsoft-oauth.  *MOST IMPORTANTLY*: 4) Engage your customer(s)  IT staff ... as early in the project as possible.

Comment: See also: [The Future of Single Sign-On Belongs to OpenID Connect](https://rcgglobalservices.com/the-future-of-single-sign-on-belongs-to-openid-connect)

Comment: WorkOS (https://workos.com/) is a great 3rd party option for integrating SSO / Directory Sync into your SaaS app